# Ultra low ripple constant-current LED driver design

Tags: led, led-driver, optics, ripple, ripple-current

I designed a LED driver(SMPS configuration) with [ILD6150XUMA1](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ILD6150-DS-v03_02-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30433cabdd35013cb490a0006ca8) and below is the circuit. I used it with [AC/DC adapter](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/WSU050-4000/237-1419-ND/3094945). The thing is, th optical system is ultra sensitive and ripple from the LED supresses the actual signal(Between 1K - 20KHz). It is the schematic and the board below:

[image: Schematics]
[image: Board]

I need to draw 1 A current per LED strings so ripples quite high in the system. The question is how can I eliminate those ripples. I calculated my limit as 5mV Vpp ripple for 1 A current draw and 5V supply. I know this is so hard to do, but I need any suggestions now. Configurations, topologies, some special cares anything. Only thing I have to do is to draw 1 A current from the LEDs and ripples should be very very less.

Comment: The datasheet gives the switching frequency as 1MHz, so are you seeing sub-harmonics in the 20kHz range? What is your measured ripple? Or are you talking about the PWM signal? Have you considered just ...not PWM dimming it?

Comment: Why don't you filter your PWM signal more - it is likely that it is ripple from this that is causing the problem.

Comment: Subharmonics are a beastly artifact of orthodox peak current mode control .If you must stick to what you have atready done then place inductance in series with the LED .

Comment: Can't you use a nice brute-force linear current source/sink?

Comment: @Daniel forgot to mention, dimming is not used in this configuration. All the system is manuel. ON and OFF. Measured ripple is 85 mV but we measure the light by a photodetector, so photodetectors signal is indeed the important one. But we can not decrease the current, I announce before you suggest.

Comment: @Andy Aka, the ripple mostly comes from the switching of the LED driver. SMPS in the chip. And I do not do dimming.

Comment: @Autistic there is an inductance in series with the LEDs. Do you mean to increase the inductance or to add an extra inductance to the LED string?

Comment: @EM Fields, I don't know what it is? Can you provide me a link or something?

Comment: I think you should add Extra inductance in series with the LED string

Comment: @Autistic If you look at the datasheet guidelines, it calls for a mere 4.7uH inductor minimum.

Comment: Using LED1 as example, the impedance of the output capacitor C4 and the ESR of the LED1 form a current divider. Lowering the impedance of C4 (increasing the capacitance) reduces the ripple current through LED1. Since you don't need PWM dimming, C4 can be arbitrarily large. It will slow down turn on or off, you can decide what is your limit there.

Comment: Looking at your PCB, you may not even have C4 laid out. Here is the ballpark: assuming the LED has ESR of 1 ohm, the inductor ripple current is 20% of 1A = 0.2A. A reduction of 100 would take that down to 0.002A. 0.002A x 1 ohm (ESR) = 2mV. So a capacitor of 0.01 ohm at 1MHz -> around 15uF. So try soldering 15uF worth of ceramic capacitors across the connector pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripple is a function of the inductor. More inductance = less ripple.

Minimum for this circuit should be 47uH for 50% ripple. You are going to need a lot more.

ESR of the cap is an efficiency issue as well as the resistance of the inductor.

Answer (score 1):

> th optical system is ultra sensitive and ripple from the LED supresses the actual signal(Between 1K - 20KHz).

Sounds like a linear driver would have been the way to go.